# What does BringOwnFeatureNotEnabled error code means in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to Create Form Recognizer through ARM. I am getting this error while passing the Key Vault details for encryption with customer managed key. I am getting this error only when attaching key vault details. Even Azure portal is also showing this error. can anyone please explain what does it means.

```
"error": {
    "code": "InvalidTemplateDeployment",
    "message": "The template deployment 'TestFormRecognizerdeployment' is not valid
 according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '367569de-8774-4ef9-a158
-a82132f19e0d'. See inner errors for details.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "BringOwnFeatureNotEnabled",
        "message": "Bring your own feature is not enabled for Subscription/SKU/Kind
."
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding you are trying to make use of **customer managed key**. Before making use of it you will have to fill out the request form here :

[Cognitive Services Customer Managed Keys and Bring Your Own Storage access request](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR3k4-f_9d9xPhWkgOUub9YhUNDZJUERRVVVDME4xNDVNRjEwMTNZV1dHSS4u)

Once this has been approved (usually takes around 5 business days).Upon the Approval, the feature responsible for the customer managed key will be activated/enabled on the subscription. You should be able to get passed the mentioned error.

Comment: @nitesh - Pls consider marking it as answer if the above helped ? :)